# Detect ongoing touch event

Tags: android, touch, android-event

I am currently trying to detect an *ongoing touch event* in my Android app.
In detail I want to recognize within a fragment whether the user touches any part of the app's screen.

Android's `OnTouchListener` works as expected except if the touch event lasts longer than a few seconds **without moving**.

For example the first 1-2 seconds of touch are being detected but everything after won't.

Is there something like an "OnPressListener" or a workaround?

Comment: Do you need a Long press listener?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out.

The solution is to use a simple `OnTouchListener`:

```
private boolean pressed = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        pressed = true;

    } else if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            || (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)) {
        pressed = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a well defined gesture you are trying to detect, have a look at GestureDetector.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   aButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked " ,
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;    // <- set to true
    }
    });
```

on your aButton and if you are using API < 19 you have to add

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

Attribute to your aButton in layout xml.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to get an event as long as the touch lasts, not only an event once the touch occured.